# IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended not working from Python when opening Excel workbook

Tags: python-2.7, win32com

I have an excel workbook I need to open from python in a writable mode. The workbook is set up to have the prompt for a [read only recommendation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prompt-to-open-a-Microsoft-Office-Word-document-as-read-only-d4332204-ee54-4e9b-bac0-532c6fc310c4) and this cannot be removed.

I am using the following:

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
filepath = 'C:\Users\FullFilePath.xlsm'
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=filepath, ReadOnly=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended=True)
```

It opens the file, but it's still popping up the dialog asking if I want to open in read only. Is it possible to cancel that dialog?

Comment: Try using `xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')`. This works without a dialog box for me.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Cheers, please accept my answer with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instead:

```
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
```

This works without a dialog box for me.