# How to pass an argument "yes" or "no" to xlwings xw.Book(myfile) where myfile is "Read-only recommended"?

Tags: xlwings

I saved an an excel file as "Read-only recommended" with name "myfile". Then I want to open it using python xlwings xw.Book(myfile). How do I pass the argument "yes" or "no" ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer would be to use the `IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended` flag, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43101074/918626), but I couldn't make that work (but maybe it works for you?).
So the only answer I can give you for now is how to open it in read-only, but not how to open it with `read-only=False`:

```
import xlwings as xw


if not xw.apps:
    app = xw.App()
else:
    app = xw.apps.active

app.display_alerts = False
wb = xw.Book(r'myfile')
app.display_alerts = True
```

Comment: Neither the first nor the second method worked for me

Answer (score 0):

A better solution turns out to be to go around both Excel and xlwings:

import os

from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH, S_IWUSR

os.chmod(myfile, S_IWUSR|S_IREAD) # turn the file to write mode

os.chmod(myfile, S_IREAD|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH) # turn back to read only

This has already been discussed elsewhere:

[Change file to read-only mode in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492685/change-file-to-read-only-mode-in-python)